# Do viruses pickup new genetic sequences from the host cell?

Tags: genetics, evolution, virology

Virus replication does not involve meiosis so the virus genome does not gain diversity from having two parents , so other than from mutation, do viruses obtain new genetic sequences from the host cell ?

Do virus genomes show evidence of containing base pair sequences which originated from host cell ?

Comment: look up the term "mutation" that is the source for new genetic sequences in sexual species as well.

Comment: Yes, it does seem that a virus can pick up transposable elements from the host — you may be interested in this related question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92829/do-any-known-viruses-contain-junk-or-parasitic-genomic-information

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See for example [this article](https://phys.org/news/2020-06-viruses-genetic-code-human-virus-genes.html), which describes how some viruses can pick up bits of human DNA.  Here's a quote from the article:

> ...researchers have shown that a large group of viruses, including the influenza viruses and other serious pathogens, steal genetic signals from their hosts to expand their own genomes.

Comment: I really like that you gave an answer, but an appropriate quote from the article would make this answer soooo much better, earn you upvotes, and defeat the effects of a broken link.

Comment: OK, added a quote.  When I tested the link, it worked.  Is it broken from your perspective?

Comment: Nope. Perfect !

Comment: “Steal genetic signals” Obviously a case for the local constabulary.

Comment: It gets worse. The article in question reckons “they steal our genetic code”. Are you sure it isn’t a tweet from that flatulent person?